# Determining endianness of machine architecture in C the correct way

Tags: c, endianness

I just wrote the following function to determine the endianness of the machine architecture (writing for an ARM Cortex-M7 architecture based MCU though, but wanted functionality to make the code portable):

```
uint8_t is_little_endian()
{
   static const union test {
      uint32_t num;
      uint8_t  bytes[sizeof(uint32_t)];
   } p = {.num =  1U };              

   return (p.bytes[0] == 1U); 
}
```

I was just wanting to know if there will be any false results if I use `unsigned int` and `char` here instead of `uint32_t` and `uint8_t` in the above code? If yes, why?

Comment: No, type signess does not matter in this case BTW what is stopping you from checking.

Comment: I just wanted to know if at all unsigned int and char will induce any false results!

Comment: If you're just after portability, wouldn't you just use functions like `ntohs` and `htons`?

Comment: don't forget mixed/middle-endian ;)

Comment: `sizeof(unsigned int)` ==> `sizeof(uint32_t)` ?

Comment: Detail, This code attempts to discern the endianness of _integers_, not the machine.  The endianness of floating point may uncommonly differ.  Compiler options can affect the result too as some machines allow either.

Comment: "wanted functionality to make the code portable" --> High portability considers that `uint8_t` is an _optional_ type.  `uint8_t` is not available when `CHAR_BIT > 8`.

Comment: @4386427, I have updated the question, I forgot to replace "unsigned int" with "uint32_t"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your immediate question, `unsigned` and `char` will work just as well **if** `CHAR_BIT < 16`. That's because the C standard requires an `unsigned` to have at least 16 value bits and every type must have a storage size that's a multiple of a `char` (a byte). So as long as your `char` has fewer than 16 bits, an `unsigned` must consist of at least 2 bytes and the endianness check will work this way.

Using `char` actually has the benefit that it's allowed to alias any other type. So I'd suggest something like this:

```
#include <limits.h>
#if CHAR_BIT > 15
#error exotic platform
#endif

int is_little_endian(void)
{
    unsigned x = 1U;
    unsigned char *r = (unsigned char *)&x;
    return !!*r;
}
```

I used `unsigned char` here just to be sure.

Be aware this assumes there's no *exotic* byte order (like "middle-endian"). Also, I personally think such code is a waste of space in the program, if you really need endianness information, it's probably better to have your build system determine it for your target and just `#define` it (e.g. in a `config.h` file).

Comment: @snr that's not strictly necessary, it "normalizes" every nonzero value to `1`.

Comment: humm, other than `0`, is every value `1` in C? I mean why not just `*r`?

Comment: this function is expected to return a *truthy* or *falsey* value. Anything not `0` is *truthy* in C, but the canonic value for *true* is `1`. Now, I *think* I can't be sure the value bits in a `char` are arranged in the same way as in an `int`, therefore reading `*r` could give any nonzero value on a little-endian machine. It would be ok to return this directly, I just thought limiting the return values to `0` and `1` is nicer ;)

Comment: humm, it's the subtle nuance. Thank you so much!

Comment: I hope 6 days go fast. I'd like to see you again here. You're valuable person for us. I reap the benefit of you too much. See you sir, Soner

Comment: is there a reason for returning !!*r instead of just *r?

Answer (score 1):

> I was just wanting to know if there will be false results if I use
>   `unsigned int` and `char` here instead of `uint32_t` and `uint8_t`? If
>   yes, why?

Yes, it may.

Types mentioned(`unsigned int` and `char`) are *implementation-defined*. It may depend on compiler, machine, compiler options etc. If you look at the types declared in [stdint.h](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/C_Reference/stdint.h). This is part of the [standard library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library), so it is expected (though technically not guaranteed) to be available everywhere. Among the types declared here are `int8_t`, `uint8_t`, `int16_t`, `uint16_t`, `int32_t`, `uint32_t`, `int64_t`, and `uint64_t`.

Comment: And here ... while it's correct that using `unsigned` and `char` **could** go wrong, the chances for this are quite narrow ;) e.g. it **can't** go wrong on a platform that actually provides a `uint8_t` type (because this requires `char` to have 8 bits as well).

Comment: Yes, your saying makes it clearer. C standard guarantees char is 8bit as well.

Comment: no it doesn't (otherwise using `char` and `unsigned` could never go wrong). Your answer is correct.

Comment: All I'm saying is it's **very** unlikely to find a platform that has more than 8 bits for `char` -- and on such a platform, the `uint8_t` type cannot exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply `return ntohs(12345) != 12345`.

Comment: if you can do, a bit explanation is better

Comment: Don't you think to explain its logic still? Middle-endian, little-endian, big-endian ??